# Updating partial properties of an entity EF Core .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Hello I have a class and I would like to update some of the properties using ef core

I have the class customer

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public string Email  { get; set; }
        public string Address  { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegisterDate  { get; set; }
    }
```

And in the persistence layer

> the first method

```
        using var db = new CustomerDbContext(_options);

        var entry = db.Customers.Attach(modification.Customer);
        entry.Property(customer => customer.Name).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(customer => customer.Email).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(customer => customer.Address).IsModified = true;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

> the second method

```
        using var db = new CustomerDbContext(_options);

        var customerEntry = db.Entry(modification.Customer);
        customerEntry.Property(customer => customer.Name).IsModified = true;
        customerEntry.Property(customer => customer.Email).IsModified = true;
        customerEntry.Property(customer => customer.Address).IsModified = true;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I try to understand what is the difference between them and what is the most efficient way?
Is there any else?

Comment: Just so I can understand better what behaviour you are trying to achieve: Why do you want to manually set the properties to be modified? Are there changes in the `modification.Customer` you do not want to persist?

Comment: @Nannanas yes I try to persist the values in db. I search around and I find these ways how to save partially data

Comment: What is `modification.Customer`? Why aren't you using the 'normal' EF (core) tracking?

Comment: @JHBonarius  this is my customer entity

Comment: Yeah, likely. But if you get the customer from DB with tracking, you can just modify it and EF will track the changes. No need to manually attach it later (that would actually be slower)

Comment: @JHBonarius I d like to work with a disconnected scenario. is it a web api